# Image opens all grey even though the thumbnail looks fine

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: preview of problem]

I'm trying to open up these images. When I view them from the folder, the thumbnail looks fine but when I open it, it's just a big grey blob. I can see some outlines so the image "is there" but for some reason, it goes grey? I've never had this happen before...

There's only one background layer and it's exactly as shown.

Channels say RGB, Red, Green, Blue.

Is it a view thing or is the image just damaged?

Comment: Images can get corrupted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Finder preview looks OK, I think Preview should be able to open them properly.

Try opening them there first. If the colors are fine, then re-save and try again in Photoshop.